# Windows Lags after installing Display Driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, display-driver

My Windows 10 pro Toshiba Satellite L360 - 170 System hangs after I installed an older version of display/graphics driver. Nothing in the system works except the mouse. I tried to uninstall the driver but it won't allow me to navigate into any windows or app? How can I change the driver to my previous one considering that I can't navigate into any application?.In General, How do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot into Safe Mode on Windows.  This will load Windows without the installed video driver.  From here, you can uninstall the driver.

Here is a [guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234) from Microsoft on various ways to boot into Safe Mode.  It sounds like you might have to (force) reboot your PC and enter safe mode from the login screen.

Comment: Solved the problem, Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the task manager (`Ctrl+Shift+Esc` or `Left click on taskbar->Task Manager`) to open device manager from there (`File->Run New Task->devmgmt.msc`).

Then you can uninstall your driver from there using your mouse only.